# Playing video in Processing

Tags: video, arduino, processing

I am reading capacitive sensors with Arduino and the number of the sensor touched is communicated to Processing, at the moment it is just 1 or 2.

In Processing, I am trying to play a video depending on the number of the sensor received. I need to be able to switch between the different videos during the time of playback, after it is finished, and if the same number is pressed the video should jump back to the start.

This is the code in Processing

```c
    import processing.serial.*;
    import processing.video.*;
    
    Movie video1, video2;
    
    Serial port;
    char in;
    char previousIn;
    boolean playing = false;
    //float time = 0;
    
    void setup() {  
      fullScreen(JAVA2D);
      frameRate(25);
      video1 = new Movie(this, "redFIN.mp4");
      video2 = new Movie(this, "greenFIN.mp4");
      port = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[0], 9600);
    }
    
    void movieEvent(Movie m) {
      m.read();
    }
    
    void draw() {  
      if ( port.available() > 0) {  // If data is available,
        in = char(port.read());
        print(in);
      }
    
      if (in == '1') {  
        video1.play();
        video2.stop();
        in = previousIn;
        if (in == previousIn) {
          video1.jump(0);
        }
      }
      image(video1, 0, 0, width, height);
    
    
      if (in =='2') {
        video2.play();
        video1.stop();
        in = previousIn;
        if (in == previousIn) {
          video2.jump(0);
        }
      }
      image(video2, 0, 0, width, height);
    }
```

At the moment, I can switch between the videos but only from movie1 to movie2, when going back from movie2 to movie1 I get the audio of the movie1 but it keeps displaying the last frame of the movie2.

I would appreciate any insight into why is this happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're super close, but still have a couple of areas that won't behave the you expect:

1. You draw both `video1` and `video2` using `image()`: you'll want to only render a single video
2. the `if (in == previousIn)` conditions should probably happen before setting `previousIn` (which btw you're setting the ohter way around). (otherwise the condition will always be true)

Here's a version using a third `Movie` variable which is simply a reference to either `video1` or `video2` depending on context:

```
import processing.serial.*;
import processing.video.*;

Movie video1, video2, currentVideo;

Serial port;
char in;
char previousIn;
boolean playing = false;
//float time = 0;

void setup() {  
  fullScreen(JAVA2D);
  frameRate(25);
  video1 = new Movie(this, "redFIN.mp4");
  video2 = new Movie(this, "greenFIN.mp4");
  // default to video1
  currentVideo = video1;
  port = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[0], 9600);
}

void movieEvent(Movie m) {
  m.read();
}

void draw() {  
  if ( port.available() > 0) {  // If data is available,
    in = char(port.read());
    print(in);
  }

  if (in == '1') {  
    video1.play();
    video2.stop();
    if (in == previousIn) {
      video1.jump(0);
    }
    previousIn = in;
    currentVideo = video1;
  }

  if (in =='2') {
    video2.play();
    video1.stop();
    if (in == previousIn) {
      video2.jump(0);
    }
    previousIn = in;
    currentVideo = video2;
  }
  
  image(currentVideo, 0, 0, width, height);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works as intended! I had figured out a different way of doing this (based on another smart person's code and with many more lines of code) but your comments and explanation are amazing for learning and a better understanding!